# Swagger Codegen does not generate generic List

Tags: java, swagger, codegen

In my api model I have:

```
@JsonProperty("repriceItems") private List<RepriceItem> items;
```

swagger (I think correct):

```
"repriceItems": { "items": { "type": "RepriceItem" }, "required": false, "type": "List" }
```

But when I run swagger codegen for Java or Android, I get:

```
private List repriceItems = null;
```

instead of

```
private List<RepriceItem> repriceItems = null;
```

I'm using codegen v 2.1.2-M1.

Is it a bug or do I something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have filed a ticket in [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues).  What you're describing should be supported.